# Support Vector Machine bad results-Python

Tags: machine-learning, svm

I'm studying SVM and implemented this code , it's too basic,primitive and taking too much time but I just wanted to see how it actually works.Unfortunately,it is giving me bad results.What did I miss? Some coding error or mathematical mistakes? If you want to look at dataset , it's link here. I taked it from UCI Machine Learning Repository. Thanks for your deal.

```
def hypo(x,q):
    return 1/(1+np.exp(-x.dot(q)))

data=np.loadtxt('LSVTVoice',delimiter='\t');

x=np.ones(data.shape)
x[:,1:]=data[:,0:data.shape[1]-1]
y=data[:,data.shape[1]-1]

q=np.zeros(data.shape[1])
C=0.002

##mean normalization
for i in range(q.size-1):
    x[:,i+1]=(x[:,i+1]-x[:,i+1].mean())/(x[:,i+1].max()-x[:,i+1].min());

for i in range(2000):
    h=x.dot(q)
    for j in range(q.size):
        q[j]=q[j]-(C*np.sum(  -y*np.log(hypo(x,q))-(1-y)*np.log(1-hypo(x,q)))  ) + (0.5*np.sum(q**2))

for i in range(y.size):
    if h[i]>=0:
        print y[i],'1'     
    else:
        print y[i],'0'
```

Comment: Maybe you should explain a bit, what the code is doing. As i don't see any library-call, i suppose you implemented some svm-algorithm by yourself? Where? The second loop? What should that be? SGD? Coordinate-descent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your data, it's very usual that Simple Implementation of SVM give you bad result. You must try advanced version on SVM implementation(e.g [Sickit SVM](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/svm.html)) you can also check this: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/tree/master/sklearn/svm

SVM has types of implementation and parameters like different kernels(e.g rbf). You must check them and try them with different parameter(depending on your data) and compare results to each other.

You can use Grid Search approach for comparing(check this: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/grid_search.html)

Comment: While there are some truths here, i think it's a bit misleading. I wouldn't call kernel-based SVMs *advanced* (although they are more complex ti implement efficiently), they are just a different model. And while there are proofs, that a kernel like rbf can approximate the solution of any linear SVM (i think), many applications are working just better with a linear approach (very high-dimensional data like NLP where CV is too much work to find that working rbf-kernel). Also: different svm-solvers(cut-planes, sgd, cd) don't really differ regarding solutions, but efficiency & parameter-dependence